# How can I statistically define such feature (independent variable) being faced on zero inflation issue?

Tags: statistical-significance, zero-inflation

here is a vector: [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,4,2,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,....,2,0] and is there any statistic test and p value to tell me such vector is holding too many zero ? I just check https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/api.html but they didn't fit my requirement. I am not statistician but I prefer to use statistic test, because of academic support, implemented by Python so as to find p value to convince my advisor that vector is facing zero inflated issue

Thank you so much

Sincerely

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Diagnostic plots for count regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70558/diagnostic-plots-for-count-regression) I'm assuming that you want to evaluate zero inflation against a Poisson distribution. In particular, see Point 5 of [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70581/28500).

Comment: Thanks ... But previously I have checked a lot of answers that are similar with your link. Generally, those zero inflation issues are designed for `Y ~ X1 + X2 + ... Xn`, but I would like to inspect `X1`, `X2` or `Xn` singgally. Here is the tutorial I found at YouTube[link](/www.youtube.com/watch?v=othUlpJG8Tg). Is there any R code or Python code ?

Comment: by the way.. Is this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118322/how-to-test-for-zero-inflation-in-a-dataset) is suitable to answer my question ??? How can I convince my boss to apply it ?? Thanks

Comment: Yes, the page you link to in the second comment is fine (more specific to your question than the one I suggested) and provides a [simple test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/262984/28500) for evaluating zero inflation versus Poisson for individual variables. Be careful: unless you know that each `Xi` is supposed to be Poisson-distributed, there might be nothing wrong with any zero inflation that you find. Sometimes real count data just have a lot of 0 values. So unless your boss accepts that the values should be Poisson distributed, it will be hard to convince.

Comment: Thank you very much~~ My problem has been resolved